# Crash when I add, then delete then add again the same object

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm building an app with SwiftUI and SwiftData where I can search recipes (with an API) and add them to my favorites.

The app crash each time I add a recipe to my favorites, then delete it and then **add it again**.
Here is the Xcode error :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "ingredients"; desired type = NSData; given type = Swift.__SwiftDeferredNSArray; value = (
> "Reciplease.Ingredient(text: "One 3 3/4- to 4-pound chicken", food: "chicken", foodId: "food_bmyxrshbfao9s1amjrvhoauob6mo")"
> ).'

It contains all the ingredients present in my recipe.

Here is my (new) Model :

```
struct ApiResponse: Decodable {
    var count: Int
    var hits: [RecipeObject]
    
    struct RecipeObject: Decodable {
        var recipe: RecipeModel
        
        struct RecipeModel: Decodable {
            var label: String
            var image: String
            var ingredients: [Ingredient]
            var url: String
            var totalTime: Double
        }
    }
}

@Model
class Recipe {
   
    var title: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var ingredients: [Ingredient]
    var url: String
    var totalTime: Double
    
    init(title: String, imageUrl: String, ingredients: [Ingredient], url: String, totalTime: Double) {
        self.title = title
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.url = url
        self.totalTime = totalTime
    }
}

extension Recipe {
    convenience init(from recipe: ApiResponse.RecipeObject.RecipeModel) throws {
        self.init(
            title: recipe.label,
            imageUrl: recipe.image,
            ingredients: recipe.ingredients,
            url: recipe.url,
            totalTime: recipe.totalTime
        )
    }
}
```

I tried to change my `struct Ingredient` to a `@Model class Ingredient`, to add `@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)` to the ingredients properties but it didn't solved the issue, same crash with same error.

Here is my App.swift

```
@main
struct RecipleaseApp: App {
    let container: ModelContainer

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .modelContainer(container)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        do {
            container = try ModelContainer(for: Recipe.self)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to configure SwiftData container.")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I fav/unfav the recipe :

```
func addRecipeToFavorite(modelContext: ModelContext, recipe: Recipe) {
    modelContext.insert(recipe)
}

func removeRecipeFromFavorite(modelContext: ModelContext, recipe: Recipe) {
    modelContext.delete(recipe)
}
```

I tried with saving the `modelContext` after each operation even if I didn't disabled autosave but again it didn't solved the issue.

The action that trigger the crash is always the **second** add to favorites, I really can't understand why.

**Edit** : I changed the structure of my code thanks to the example sent by lorem ipsum, I tried to play with `@Environment` but I have the same crash that happens at the same action as before.

**Edit 2** : I just removed the `Ingredient` struct from the Model and all the views and it works. But I need this property so it is not the solution.